# configure kafka connect sink for elastic search 7.1 using docker compose

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-kafka-connect

I am setting up a producer that sends messages as a (key value) [`key` is a generated unique `string`, `value` is a `json` payload ] to kafka topics (v1.0.0) that are pulled by a kafka connect(v5.3.1) which is then sent to an Elastic search container(v 7.1).

The kafka connect is configured to look at ES for an index with the topic name (the index is already mapped on ES with a schema) and uses kafka `key` as the unique id(_id) for every document inserted into the index. Once producer puts content into the kafka topic, it has to be pulled by connect and sent to the ES.

The kafka connect (5.3.1) needs the value sent to it from kafka topic to be of the form as below, in order to map it to elastic search index

```
{
"schema": {es_schema },
"payload":{ es_payload }
}
```

My producer is only able to send

```
{
es_payload
}
```

I am using docker/docker-compose containers to simulate this locally

I have the producer being able to send to kafka and gets picked up by kafka connect but fails on sending to elastic stating that schema not found on payload

My configuration for kafka connect sink

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8083/connectors/ \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "name": "elasticsearch-sink",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "adn-kafka",
    "key.ignore": "false",
    "schema.ignore": "false",
    "connection.url": "http://elasticsearch:9200",
    "type.name": "",
    "name": "elasticsearch-sink",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable":"false"
  }
}'
```

The error I get

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires "schema" and "payload" fields and may not contain additional fields. If you are trying to deserialize plain JSON data, set schemas.enable=false in your converter configuration.
     at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:338)
     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$0(WorkerSinkTask.java:510)
     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
     ... 13 more
```

if I set  `schema.ignore : true`, it does not look for an index with the schema and i don think thats the right way cause my index is already mapped and i dont want kafka connect to send to create a new index

my docker compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    container_name : zookeeper
    image: zookeeper
    ports:
     - 2181:2181
     - 2888:2888
     - 3888:3888

  kafka:
    container_name : kafka
    image: bitnami/kafka:1.0.0-r5
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: "42"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "kafka"
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: "yes" 

  elasticsearch:
    container_name : elasticsearch
    image:
      elasticsearch:7.1.1
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - node.name=node1
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms4g -Xmx4g"
      - discovery.type=single-node

    ports:
      - "9400:9200"
      - "9500:9300"
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 6G
        reservations:
          memory: 6G
  kibana:
    container_name : kibana
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.1.1
    # environment:
      # - SERVER_NAME=Local kibana
      # - SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0
      # - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=elasticsearch:9400
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  kafka-connect:
    container_name : kafka-connect
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.3.1
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    volumes:
      - $PWD/connect-plugins:/connect-plugins
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "kafka:9092"
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: kafka-connect
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-kafka-connect-configs
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-kafka-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-kafka-connect-status
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER-SCHEMAS_ENABLE: "false"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER-SCHEMAS_ENABLE: "false"
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "kafka-connect"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: "INFO"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=WARN,org.reflections=ERROR"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: '/usr/share/java'
      # Interceptor config
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-5.3.1.jar
```

kafka topic name : `test-kafka`

Es index : `test-kafka`

ES mapping

```
{
    "mappings":{
        "properties" :{
            "ppid":{
                "type":"long"
            },
            "field1":{
                "type":"long"
            },
            "field2":{
                "type":"long"
            },
            "time1":{
                "type":"date",
                "format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            },
            "time2":{
                "type":"date",
                "format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            },
            "status":{
                "type":"keyword"
            },
            "field3":{
                "type":"integer"
            },
            "field4":{
                "type":"integer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

payload being sent to kafka topic

```
{ "ppid" : 1, "field1":2 , "field2":1,"time1":"2019-09-25 07:36:48", "time2":"2019-09-25 07:36:48", "status":"SUCCESS", "field3":30,"field4":16}
```

Comment: You have a typo in the compose on the schema enablement. Dashes should be replaced with underscores. And that property is only valid on the JSONConverter, so your key converter doesn't need it

Comment: Thanks a lot ..  Also i had to make `"schema.ignore": "true", because it fails to map otherwise

Comment: @PraveenSureshkumar did you find a solution to this problem? What was the solution?